# Onboard motherboard's graphics card not output

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, gpu

## The problem

My motherboard's HDMI port isn't working

## Research and work so far

> Internet says integrated GPU is disabled by default when a discrete GPU is connected.

I did enabled the integrated graphics on the BIOS settings.

> Internet says sometimes the monitor's drivers take a time to kick in.

I left the pc run long enough time.

> Internet says running Windows Update may force the dirvers to install.

Have runned Windows Update until no avaliable updates are avaliable. Nothing changed.

So, I explicitly installed the lastest [VGA Intel controller](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MPG-Z490-GAMING-CARBON-WIFI#down-driver&Win10%2064) in my motherboard's website.
Once installed it tries to run the monitor attached to the GPU.
My system doesn't detect a new monitor has been connected. The port should be enabled now.
I did restarded many times so changes kick in. No changes. Any ideas?

### System

- OS: Win10 ver.2004
- motherboard: MSI z490 gaming carbon wifi
- CPU: Intel i7-10700K
- GPU: Nvidia 2070 RTX Super

I assume the rest of componnets are meaningless to this problem. But can provide the info if needed.
All drivers should be up to date, but system in brand new (less than a week old)

### PD

There's one HDMI cable connecting from the a GPU's HDMI port to my main monitor, and there's another cable connecting the motherboard's HDMI port to me secondary monitor.

## EDIT

After @SamForbis's suggestions I'll add more info about.

- The Devices Manager, under the Display Adapters section shows both Intel's and Nvidia Drivers [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S16bh.jpg).
  This happend after the Intel's drivers installation, before it only showed the Nvidia ones.
- Although under Monitors, it only shows one [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDUkM.jpg)
- I have tried to connect the secondary monitor in the GPU's port, and it works, and connected the main monitor into the on-boad port and doesn't work.
- At the momment I don't have any DisplayPort cable of any kind, so I can't test the DP port in the motherboard.

Comment: If you open Device Manager and look under "Display Adapters", what do you see? Do you only see the dedicated GPU or do you see the integrated Intel adapter as well?

Comment: @SamForbis After the Inter Drivers instalation it shows [screenshot](https://imgur.com/d0mWFPh), not before. But still doesn't find the second monitor

Comment: Have you tried connecting the "main" monitor to the on-board HDMI port to ensure that the issue is not with the cable and/or the second monitor you are trying to use?

Comment: @SamForbis I have. Connected the main monitor to the on-board port: no signal. Connected the secondary monitor to the GPU port: works

Comment: Thanks, you should edit your question to include that information and the screenshot you gave me as well as what operating system you are running (I assume Windows 10). At this point, it sounds like either a bad driver or a bad port on the motherboard. Is there any way for you to try using the DisplayPort interface on your motherboard to see if it's just the HDMI port that isn't working?

Comment: @SamForbis Thank you, will edit in a moment. And no, I don't have any kind DisplayPort cable available (neither DP-DP nor DP-HDMI; that's the reason why I tried to use the on-board port on the first place xD)